# problem convert bytes to string in Python

Tags: python, string, ascii

I have file named `**.bxl` and I try to read this file in Python as follow:

```
import chardet
bxl_file = open(bxl_filename,'rb')
bxl_str = bxl_file.readlines()[0]
the_encoding = chardet.detect(bxl_str)['encoding']
bxl_str = bxl_str.decode(the_encoding)
bxl_file.close()
```

When I print `bxl_str` , it looks fine like this:[image]
However it does not work when I directly show it as:[image]

What I want is to get a string just as the `print(bxl_str)` result. Any one who can help me ? Appreciated!!
[Link for the file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=16_UtnS-l5Y1T6V5iPePAzGDCvL-iTyqP)

Comment: you have problem here - bxl_file.readlines()[0] but you want your string to look like this - bxl_str.decode(the_encoding)

Comment: @PySaad Sorry that I do not understand what you mean?pls

Comment: That looks like a possibly fixed-length binary format. I.e. it’s not meant to be read directly as plain text, but should be parsed to some degree or another.

Comment: @deceze I have added the file in the description. Could you please have a look?Thank you .

Comment: Without knowledge of the purpose of the file, I don't think anyone can tell you anything more than "this is not an encoding; you're doing it wrong". Probably `print` on your system doesn't produce any visible output for control characters; you could approximate this in Python with something like splitting on control characters and assuming the extracted fragments can simply be decoded as `ascii`. See also hhe Unix `strings` utility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you are experiencing is result of the fact that when you insert a variable into the interpreter, it displays it's **repr** attribute whereas print() takes the **str** (which are the same in this scenario) and ignores all unprintable characters such as: \x00, \x01 and replaces them with something else (i'm guessing white space).

An optional solution if you don't care about the spacing:

```
''.join(x for x in bxl_str if x.isprintable())
```

Or if you do care about spacing:

```
spaced_str = ''
for char in bxl_str:
    if char.isprintable():
        spaced_str += char
    else:
        spaced_str += ' '
```

Or in a more pythonic way (thank you Dan):

```
''.join(char if char.isprintable() else ' ' for char in bxl_str)
```

Comment: It’s not that str replaces the characters with white space, it’s that the terminal doesn’t print those *unprintable* characters (well, it does, it just doesn’t look like anything), while repr explicitly visualizes unprintable characters.

Comment: Nothing pythonic about `map`. Rather use a comprehension: `''.join(char if char.isprintable() else ' ' for char in bxl_str)`

Answer (score 0):

what tripleee said in a comment holds, but this is a guess...

it looks like some sort of "data dictionary", i.e. giving descriptive names to otherwise opaque/numeric values.  there seem to be some sort of sectioning going on, with 37 to 44 `NUL` characters between distinct sets of values.  each set of values seems to have key/value pairs also separated by `NUL` chars, and I'd use the following code to interpret this file:

```
import re

with open('Links.bxl', encoding='ascii') as fd:
    buf = fd.read()

for section in re.split('\x00{32,}', buf):
    print('Next Section')
    section = section.split('\x00')
    for i in range(1, len(section), 2):
        print(' {0!r} => {1!r}'.format(section[i-1], section[i]))
    if len(section) % 2 == 1:
        print(repr(section[-1]))
```

the first few lines of output from the above is:

```
Next Section
'\x01'
Next Section
'Class'
Next Section
 '0' => 'Undefined'
 '11' => 'Freeway'
 '21' => 'Expressway'
 '31' => 'Major Arterial'
 '41' => 'Minor Arterial'
 '51' => 'Local Street'
 '61' => 'Access Road'
 '81' => 'Ramp'
 '82' => 'UnderRoad'
 '83' => 'TAZ_Link'
 '84' => 'Interchange_Ramp'
 '85' => 'UnderLine'
 '' => 'Disabled_AB'
Next Section
 '0' => 'No'
 '1' => 'Yes'
 '' => 'Disabled_BA'
```